# Min number of players in multiplayer game

Tags: probability, self-study, games

Suppose in a multiplayer game, we have a match being played for which we need `X` players, when the number of players is less than `X` the match will not take place.

In addition a player waits a maximum of `Z` seconds until the required `X` players gather, if the waiting time is greater than `Z` the player quits

How many willing players `N` do we need for the match to take place with at least `P` probability.

Assumptions:

```
X = 10
Z = 120
P = 0.75
```

I am not able to provide the distribution of their waiting times but lets suppose that most of them (>90%) will not wait longer than `Z` sec.

Comment: The information you supply is incomplete and does not permit a solution.   What is the distribution of their waiting times?  What are the initial conditions? Why does the duration of the match matter?

Comment: hi @whuber just edited the questions, could you point me to the right direction?

Comment: I know you've already made some edits but I still don't think there's enough here to permit a solution. Some questions/comments that I have: (i) I assume the players will sit in a lobby until the number of players is at least $X$. What process describes how they arrive? (ii) You said that $90\%$ of players will not wait more than $Z$ seconds, you also said if the waiting time is greater than $Z$ the player leaves - these statements are not compatible. (iii) What is a 'willing player'? If I have $N>X$ willing players, surely the game will just go ahead?

Comment: This question fits within the discipline of *queuing theory.*  You might find it useful to review some of our [many posts about queuing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=queu*) to get a sense of what this is about and what additional information is required to make your question answerable.  At a minimum, you need to make quantitative assumptions about the time distribution of arrivals of players and the amount of time available before the game might be called off.